# Relation between rain, time and terrains

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, friction, water

I would like to understand whether an approximate relation between the rain and the physical properties of a particular terrain (composed of a specific material such as asphalt or clay or grass or plastic, etc.) exists as a function of time.

In this request, I'd like to understand, even in an approximate way, also which physical properties of the terrain the rain impacts. For instance, the friction or the absorption of water by the terrain.

Basically, I would like to get a better idea on the effect of the rain / water to terrains. I have a hard time even finding material on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you interested in rain and water erosion?

Comment: More in rain than water erosion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some search topics to try, which will probably get you started on answering your questions.

First, in the field of *civil engineering* you will find treatment of *surface water drainage and management* which deals with the response of terrain (paved and unpaved) to rain water.

Second, in the fields of *soil science* and *range agronomy* you will find treatment of rain response of different types of soils on drainage, percolation and subsurface water movement.

Comment: Super. It seems a good starting point, I am going to deepen these fields